# MySQL calculate duration by date till end of date using lead function

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that stores the records for users' different sessions(subscribe, unsubscribe, away, online). I am able to calculate the time duration for each session using the following given query.
There is a scenario that supposes a user starts his online session on "15-May-2022 at 11:00:00 PM", after that on the next day he set himself away on "16-May-2022 at 02:00:00 AM"
Total online is 3 Hours which I am getting as the last row on the date 15-May-2022.

But I need like this
On 15-May till "15-May-2022 23:59:59" it was online for 1 Hour and on 16-May from "16-May-2022 00:00:00 to 16-May-2022 at 02:00:00 AM", it was online for 2 Hours. So in response, it should return 1 hour for 15-May and 2 hours for 16-May, not a total of 3 hours on 15-May.

I am using the lead function to get the duration from the created_at column, is there any way in which I can restrict the lead function to calculate duration till the next created_at till 23:59:59.

Here is my working query. I am using the latest MySQL(8) version.

```
select `id`, `user_id`, `status`, `created_at`,
 SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, created_at,
LEAD(created_at) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY created_at))) as duration,
 date(created_at) as date from `user_websocket_events` as `all_status`
 where created_at between '2022-05-15 00:00:00' and '2022-05-16 23:59:59' and `status` is not null
 and user_id in (69) order by `id` asc;
```

Here is some sample data.

```
INSERT INTO user_websocket_events (id, user_id, event, status, extra_attributes, created_at, updated_at) VALUES (10816, 69, 'subscribe', 'online', null, '2022-05-15 12:57:31', '2022-05-14 10:57:37');
INSERT INTO user_websocket_events (id, user_id, event, status, extra_attributes, created_at, updated_at) VALUES (10817, 69, 'away', 'away', null, '2022-05-15 20:57:31', '2022-05-14 10:57:37');
INSERT INTO user_websocket_events (id, user_id, event, status, extra_attributes, created_at, updated_at) VALUES (10818, 69, 'online', 'online', null, '2022-05-15 22:57:31', '2022-05-14 10:57:37');
INSERT INTO user_websocket_events (id, user_id, event, status, extra_attributes, created_at, updated_at) VALUES (10819, 69, 'away', 'away', null, '2022-05-16 02:57:31', '2022-05-14 10:57:37');
INSERT INTO user_websocket_events (id, user_id, event, status, extra_attributes, created_at, updated_at) VALUES (10820, 69, 'unsubscribe', 'unsubscribe', null, '2022-05-16 03:57:31', '2022-05-14 10:57:37');
```

Comment: If a duration of a session originally can span over more than 2 days you need a calendar table to split it by days.

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle it using `CASE` statement.

Now instead of the actual `created_at` and `LEAD(created_at)`, we need something like below.

**First Case:**

If the `created_at` and `LEAD(created_at)` falls on different date, then consider date(created_at) + '23:59:59' else consider created_at as **ENDTIME**.

```
CASE
                  WHEN Date(lead_created_at)=Date(created_at) THEN lead_created_at
                  ELSE Addtime(Timestamp(Date(created_at)),'23:59:59')
END
```

**Second Case:**

If the `created_at` and `LAG(created_at)` falls on different date, then consider date(created_at) + '00:00:00' else consider created_at as **STARTTIME**.

```
CASE
                  WHEN Date(lag_created_at)=Date(created_at) THEN created_at
                  ELSE Timestamp(Date(created_at))
END
```

Finally, the query can be written as below to get the desired output.

```sql
SELECT   `id`,
         `user_id`,
         `status`,
         `created_at`,
         CASE
                  WHEN Date(lag_created_at)=Date(created_at) THEN created_at
                  ELSE Timestamp(Date(created_at))
         end new_starttime,
         CASE
                  WHEN Date(lead_created_at)=Date(created_at) THEN lead_created_at
                  WHEN lead_created_at is null then null
                  ELSE Addtime(Timestamp(Date(created_at)),'23:59:59')
         end AS new_endtime,
         Sec_to_time(Timestampdiff(second,
         CASE
                  WHEN Date(lag_created_at)=Date(created_at) THEN created_at
                  ELSE Timestamp(Date(created_at))
         end,
         CASE
                  WHEN Date(lead_created_at)=Date(created_at) THEN lead_created_at
                  WHEN lead_created_at is null then null
                  ELSE Addtime(Timestamp(Date(created_at)),'23:59:59')
         end )) AS duration,
         date
FROM     (
                  SELECT   `id`,
                           `user_id`,
                           `status`,
                           `created_at`,
                           (Lead(created_at) over (partition BY user_id ORDER BY created_at))                   AS lead_created_at,
                           coalesce(lag(created_at) over (partition BY user_id ORDER BY created_at),created_at) AS lag_created_at,
                           date(created_at)                                                                     AS date
                  FROM     `user_websocket_events`                                                              AS `all_status`
                  WHERE    created_at BETWEEN '2022-05-15 00:00:00' AND      '2022-05-16 23:59:59'
                  AND      `status` IS NOT NULL
                  AND      user_id IN (69) )tmp
ORDER BY `id` ASC;
```

**Resultset:**

| id | user_id | status | created_at | new_starttime | new_endtime | duration | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10816 | 69 | online | 2022-05-15 12:57:31 | 2022-05-15 12:57:31 | 2022-05-15 20:57:31 | 08:00:00 | 2022-05-15 |
| 10817 | 69 | away | 2022-05-15 20:57:31 | 2022-05-15 20:57:31 | 2022-05-15 22:57:31 | 02:00:00 | 2022-05-15 |
| 10818 | 69 | online | 2022-05-15 22:57:31 | 2022-05-15 22:57:31 | 2022-05-15 23:59:59 | 01:02:28 | 2022-05-15 |
| 10819 | 69 | away | 2022-05-16 02:57:31 | 2022-05-16 00:00:00 | 2022-05-16 03:57:31 | 03:57:31 | 2022-05-16 |
| 10820 | 69 | unsubscribe | 2022-05-16 03:57:31 | 2022-05-16 03:57:31 | null | null | 2022-05-16 |

**Note:**  The query will not handle the scenario where sessions last more than 48 hour.

DB Fiddle: [Try it here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=58968ba503645d172777b60817d86323)

Comment: This will not handle sessions more than 48 hours

Comment: @Abinash will let you know after tesing.

Comment: Also please note that `lag/lead` have 3 arguments, where the third one is a default value applied when `lag/lead` goes beyond partition boundary. `coalesce(lag(...), value)` may be replaced by `lag(..., 1, value)`

Comment: Thanks @astentx, I didn't consider the sessions having more than 48 hour scenario. In that case we have to go with [Serg's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6219979/serg) answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using an on-the-fly calendar table to split a session by days

```
with recursive calendar as (
      select timestamp('2022-05-01 00:00') start_time, timestamp('2022-05-01 23:59:59')  end_time, 1 id 
      union all
      select start_time + interval 1 day, end_time + interval 1 day, id+1
      from calendar
      where id < 100
)
select e.id,  e.status, date(greatest(c.start_time, e.created_at)) date,
   greatest(c.start_time, e.created_at) as created_at,
   least(c.end_time, e.ended_at) as ended_at
from (
   select `id`, `user_id`, `status`, `created_at`,
     -- a session end is restricted to the end of the requierd interval 
     LEAD(created_at, 1, '2022-05-16 23:59:59') OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY created_at) as ended_at
   from `user_websocket_events` 
   where 
     -- only sessions started within the requierd interval 
     created_at between '2022-05-15 00:00:00' and '2022-05-16 23:59:59' and `status` is not null
     and user_id in (69) 
   ) e
join calendar c on c.start_time < e.ended_at and e.created_at < c.end_time
order by id;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3473e8b43512668740369754a31b3fb9)

Comment: Hi @Serg thanks, I will test it and then let you know.